# Availability of HttpClientFactory for Azure Functions v2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I want to know if HttpClientFactory or similar is available for Azure Functions v2.

Below is what is recommended, but HttpClientFactory or similar is not shown.

```
// Create a single, static HttpClient
private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

public static async Task Run(string input)
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://example.com");
    // Rest of function
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections

Below is a good link but I am not sure if it can be used on production, or **an official feature is available.**

https://www.tpeczek.com/2018/12/alternative-approach-to-httpclient-in.html

**Update:**

Problem to solve

1 Providing managed HttpClient pool instead of single HttpClient, like HttpClientFactory in ASP.NET CORE 2.2

Comment: "Below is a good link but I am not sure if it can be used on production." Why wouldn't it?

Comment: What is wrong with the suggestion in the second link? Looks Ok to me

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But I also want to find out if an official feature is available.

Comment: @Pingpong I have updated the answer which involves using an official feature. Let me know if it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Update

Since the original answer has been posted, the Azure Functions have been updated and there is a [new FunctionStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection) class to use instead of `IWebJobsStartup`:

**Note**: You will first need to install the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/)

```cs
using MyNamespace.Functions;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace.Functions
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

### Original Answer

Using the latest Azure Function v2 runtime, `IHttpClientFactory` is indeed available to you since the Azure Function v2 runtime has been moved to ASP.Net Core 2.2:

[Release v2.0.12265](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12265)

First, you can provide an implementation for `IWebJobsStartup` where you will define what services to inject.

Add a reference to the NuGet package `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` and use the extension method `AddHttpClient()` so that the `HttpClient` instance your Azure Functions will receive will come from an `IHttpClientFactory`.

```cs
using MyNamespace.Functions;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace MyNamespace.Functions
{
    public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then update your Azure Function by removing the `static` keywords and add a constructor to enable the injection of the instance of `HttpClient` built by the internal -I think- `DefaultHttpClientFactory` instance:

```
public sealed class MyFunction()
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyFunction(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public void Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "v1/resource/{resourceId}")] HttpRequest httpRequest, string resourceId)
    {
         return OkObjectResult($"Found resource {resourceId}");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sue if using single instance of HttpClient is the correct way. part of the thread is to use HttpClient pool

Comment: @Pingpong I have updated the answer so that the `HttpClient` your Azure Function receives is provided to you via `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: the Run is now instance method, is it static Run() method better?

Comment: @Pingpong I am not sure if instance method makes it better... well, for the testing aspect, I do think it is better. But the real benefit here is the injection part... and somewhat mimics what we have with an ASP.Net Core Controller.

Comment: Thx. Answered!!

Comment: Not sure if you have info on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033813/model-binding-for-function-parameters-for-http-request-with-c-sharp-in-azure-fuc

Comment: This answer is out of data and appears to be broken. IWebJobsStartup should be FunctionsStartup, etc. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

You could provide a full working example vs what you have above.

Comment: @ChrisWeber Thanks for the heads up. I have added the newer stuff.

Comment: For n00bs like me, I thought I'd add you also need to install the Nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Http or you'll get the error _IServiceCollection does not contain a defintion for AddHttpClient_

Comment: So I took your advice using the FunctionStart up way instead of the web jobs way. When the functions start up I get this error 

"Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IFunctionsHostBuilder.get_Services()'."

I notice I only get this error if I have    builder.Services.AddHttpClient(); inside the method.

Any takes on this guys?

Comment: @Pat Do you have all the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#prerequisites)?

Comment: Yes. I figured out I was using a Preview version of the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
Once I rolled that back to last stable everything worked