# Model binding for function parameters for HTTP request with C# in Azure Fucntion 2.x

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

Below is Azure Functions via C# with visual studio. The problem is that `req.Form` is used to create `RequestDto` object like below:

```
 public class Function1
{   
    [FunctionName("Token")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequest req)
    {

        var reqDto = new RequestDto
        {
            UserName = req.Form["username"],
            Password = req.Form["password"],
            ClientId = req.Form["client_id"],
            ClientSecret = req.Form["client_secret"]                
        };
       ...

      }
    }
```

Is it possible to use model binding that populates `RequestDto` automatically with ASP.NET CORE 2.x like below?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ConnectController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("token")]
    [Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Token([FromForm]RequestDto request)
    {
         ...
    }
 }

  public class RequestDto
  {
    [FromForm(Name="client_id")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "client_secret")]
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is there any issue with calling `Token`? Share us more information about your issue.

Comment: I want the RequestDto be automated populated like the second example when using ASP.NET CORE.

Comment: How will you request token action?

Comment: that is not relevant to the topic

Comment: For binding, it is related two parts, action parameter and client request. Without information related with client request, how can we share how to bind the model?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a custom binding or as called by Microsoft: Azure Functions/WebJobs binding extension. How to do this is explained here:
https://github.com/Azure/WebJobsExtensionSamples

Comment: So there is no built-in support for this.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.